# Transforming climate text data to raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, text, climate

I have climate data in text files with no header in the format below from [Udel's climate program](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/Global2011/README.GlobalTsT2011.html).  Each row has a lat, lon, and a temperature for each month (14 columns total) from 1900-2010.  I need to generate a Raster layer for each year-month (1320 rasters) in ArcGIS Desktop 10.

I'm thinking the likely solution is a script to parse the existing text files to create an ESRI-formatted ASCII for each year-month and then use ArcToolbox to batch import ASCII to Raster.  However, I don't have any experience writing scripts.

Another option I considered is if there is a way to import a table or dbf to raster, but I couldn't find that operation.  Or, there may be another transformation that I'm not considering.

[image]

Comment: Create an XY layer as points (you might want to format with Excel then copy to geodatabase table) with the Lat/Lon fields then convert to a raster with IDW, Kriging or Spline (or all 3 and see how they look). If you don't want to script this then you can use iteration in a model selecting each year/month but I suspect the best way is to use python.